# Mutually exclusive EC2 instances for same autoscaling group with different target groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I have an AWS EC2 autoscaling group as part of an EB environment with 2 load balancer target groups attached, I'd like to route requests to either target group based on a query parameter specified in the request (for which I have a listener rule in the load balancer).

I'd like the 2 target groups to always use different EC2 instances, currently they overlap (the same EC2 instance is in both groups). Is there a way to achieve this using the same autoscaling group or must I have separate autoscaling groups?

Comment: You need to have separate ASGs.

Comment: @Marcin thanks! Got it to work using different ASGs